# Magento2.3 how to create Cart price rule only specific category with same assigned product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

Magento2.3: I have four categories category1, category2, category3, and category4 and I have one product (Product-A). I assigned Product-A to all categories (Cat...1 to cat...4). Now I plan to create a "Cart Price Rule" for Category4 with a 5% discount.

So how to create a Cart price rule only for Category4. If I go to Product-A through Category1 or 2 or 3, that 5% coupon code should not apply. It's only applicable for Product-A through Category4. Any suggestion, please...

Answer (score 0):

In the Conditions section when creating the rule you choose the category according to your needs. When a category is selected, it will apply to the products in that category
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/images/images/price-rule-cart-subselection-category.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible as per default magento. As it only checks whether the products are assigned to a category or not.
So in your case all categories will be matched and the rule will be applied!